# Proving logical equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been stuck on this one problem for a couple of days now with no clue on how to complete it. I need to prove the following logical equivalence:

```
~((~q ^ ~p) v (r ^ q) v (r ^ ~p)) = (~q -> ~p) -> ~(q -> r)
```

If anyone could shed some light on this matter, please...

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ask this question at math.stackexchange. Is this your homework ?

Comment: Using a truth table is the very simplest way to do it. You only need eight rows since there are three variables involved.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will post the question at math.stackexchange. Moreover, I need to prove it both algebraically and with a truth table (which I have already done)